# Some Bootstrap components not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

so Im trying to use Bootstrap component like Modals and popovers but nothing is shown specially when I try to click on the button to show the modal Fading , same thing for popover!
Here is my code I used from "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/"
I don't know what's the problem really ! Any help

Comment: Bootstrap 4  need jQuery and popperjs for popover did you have been include it in react ?

Comment: yes I did with "npm " but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

1. You can include `jquery` and `bootstrap` using CDN / Local in tag head your index.html file in public folder,

   codesandbox example : [Plain Bootstrap 4 in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/plain-bootstrap-4-in-react-pcnlg?file=/public/index.html)
2. You can use all in the box component from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

   codesandbox example : [react-bootstrap working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-working-example-o8pcb?file=/src/App.js)